# How to change paragraph text size working with itext

Tags: android, pdf, text, itext, size

i am generating a pdf file. Everything works fine. Now I want to increase the paragraph text size in my pdf document but don't know how.

Here is my code

```
Font f = new Font(Font.FontFamily.TIMES_ROMAN, 25.0f, Font.BOLD, BaseColor.BLACK);
Chunk c = new Chunk("Ergebnisse");
c.setBackground(BaseColor.RED);
Paragraph p1 = new Paragraph(c);
document.add(p1);
p1.setAlignment(Paragraph.ALIGN_CENTER);
```

I want the text "`Ergebnisse`" to get bigger and centered in the middle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code was *almost* correct:

```
Font f = new Font(Font.FontFamily.TIMES_ROMAN, 25.0f, Font.BOLD, BaseColor.BLACK);
// you created a font, but you never used it:
Chunk c = new Chunk("Ergebnisse", f);
c.setBackground(BaseColor.RED);
Paragraph p1 = new Paragraph(c);
// you changed the alignment AFTER adding p1 to the document
p1.setAlignment(Paragraph.ALIGN_CENTER);
document.add(p1);
```

So:

1. use `f` when creating the `Chunk`.
2. switch the last two lines in your code snippet.